# Simplifying stata script with a loop

Tags: loops, stata

I'm trying to create three individual dta files for three different variables that creates a new var for a select dxcode (then collapses it to the id) and assigns every record in the newly created variable a value of 1. Then with these new dta files I will merge them with a larger table. My question is, is there any way to simplify the lines of code below (perhaps with a loop since they seem to all do the same thing)?

```
*Menin variable***
*****************************
use "C:\ICD9study.dta",clear
keep if inlist(dxcode, "32290")
collapse(max) date, by(bene_id)
gen menin = 1
save "C:\Users\Desktop\temp\menin.dta",replace


*BMenin variable***
***************************************
use "C:\ICD9study.dta",clear
keep if inlist(dxcode, "32090")
collapse(min) date, by(bene_id)
gen Bmenin = 1
save "C:\Users\Desktop\temp\Bmenin.dta",replace


*nonBmenin variable***
*********************************************
use "C:\ICD9study.dta",clear
keep if inlist(dxcode, "04790")
collapse(max) date, by(bene_id)
gen nonBmenin = 1
save "C:\Users\Desktop\temp\nonBmenin.dta",replace
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a sketch, as nothing in your question is reproducible.

```
local codes 32290 32090 04790  

foreach v in menin Bmenin nonBmenin { 
    use "C:\ICD9study.dta", clear
    gettoken code codes : codes 
    keep if dxcode == "`code'"
    collapse (max) date, by(bene_id)
    gen `v' = 1
    save "C:\Users\Desktop\temp/`v'.dta", replace
}
```

Your code produces the maximum date in two cases and the minimum in one. If that is really what you want, you'll need to rewrite the code.

There is plenty of advice about good practice on the site and under the `Stata` tag wiki.

Comment: Sorry! I deleted it because it didn't seem like a good question based on your previous response. So I tried to post it again in the same format as another question I posted  this week (which someone was able to provide the loop and advice for simplification). I thought this format would increase the responses I could get.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The small problem is that deleting your thread deletes replies too. Let's leave it there.